# symfony2: insert ace in class

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I have this error when I try add ace in class:

> Warning: PDO::quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in .../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 568

My code:

```
$oid = new ObjectIdentity('class', new Post());

$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');

try {
    $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($oid);
} catch (AclAlreadyExistsException $exists) {
    return;
}

$builder = new MaskBuilder();
$builder->add('view');
$mask = $builder->get();

$acl->insertClassAce(new RoleSecurityIdentity('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'), $mask);

$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

Any idea?

Comment: With this message should have came a stack trace also. As I can't get behind a conputer keyboard for several hours, could you add it to your question? Maybe it will also show you the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try defining your object identity like so:

```
$entityoid = new ObjectIdentity('class', 'YourComp\\YourBundleBundle\\Entity\\Post');
```